# Domain transfer from Network Solutions to AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, nameserver

I am looking for a solution to mitigating 2 days of downtime.

I reached out to network solutions and they do not have control over the TTL of the Name Server records (which is 2 days or 172800 seconds).

Current Strategy

Planned Migration Steps :

Migrate Name server - First Migrating Nameserver to AWS.

Step 1: Create a Hosted zone in AWS Route 53.

Step 2: Add DNS Entries from Network Solution to Route 53.

Step 3: Replace Name server in Network solution form default to AWS Hosted Zone Name Server.

Step 4: Verify Name Server successful migration. After the successful migration of nameserver to AWS Route 53, any further changes to the DNS entries need to be made through Route 53.

2. Migrate Domain - Migrate Domain to AWS:

Step 1: Unlock domain from Network Solution.

Step 2: Initiate Domain Migration Steps from Route 53

Step 3: Verify email sent from AWS for verification purposes.

Step 4: Provide Authorization Token To AWS

Step 5: Validate Domain Migration

Step 6: Enable Transfer Lock.

Please advise if there are any other recommendations to mitigating 2 days of downtime.

Answer (score 1):

Your plan is correct. Except for one thing. Once the domain is brought live on a different registrar you might need to configure the NS records to point to Route 53. Sometimes after the transfer the NS records are set to defaults by the registrar.

Additionally, the problem here occurs *if* your existing registrar decides to remove your DNS hosting at the moment the domain name is transferred.

What happens is that there is a period of time between the old registrar seeing the transfer away of the domain, and the new registrar bringing it online. In addition, cached DNS entries may still point to the original registrar for NS records.

Until the domain is live on the new registrar, and the cached DNS has expired, the original registrar must keep your DNS related services active. If they don’t, your services may be interrupted for a few hours.

Personally, I have never had this problem but there was a recent post here on StackExchange where I interacted with a user using GoDaddy. GoDaddy decided that they would immediately, and automatically turn off the DNS hosting as soon as they received the notice of the domain transfer. Requests for `domain.com` no longer had functioning NS records. This caused an interruption to the service until everything was live on the new registrar and the changes propagated to the TLD.